# NodeJS: How can I scrape two different tables, that are visually part of the same table, into one JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, html-table

Here's an example of the table of data I'm scraping:

[image: Sample Table]

The elements in red are in the `<th>` tags while the elements in green are in a `<td>` tag,  the `<tr>` tag can be displayed according to how they're grouped (i.e. '1' is in it's own `<tr>`; HTML snippet:

EDIT: I forgot to add the surrounding div

```
<div class="table-cont">
    <table class="tg-1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-phtq">ID</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-0pky">1</td>
                <td class="tg-0pky">2</td>
                <td class="tg-0pky">3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="tg-2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="tg-phtq">Sample1</td>
                <th class="tg-phtq">Sample2</td>
                <...the rest of the table code matches the pattern...>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-0pky">Swimm</td>
                <td class="tg-dvpl">1:30</td>
                <...>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <...the rest of the table code...>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see, in the HTML they're actually two different tables while they're displayed in the above example as only one.  I want to generate a JSON object where the `keys` and `values` include the data from the two tables as if they were one, and output a single JSON Object.

How I'm scraping it right now is a bit of modified javascript code I found on a tutorial:

EDIT: In the below, I've been trying to find a way to select all relevant `<th>` tags from both tables and insert them into the same array as the rest of the `<th>` tag array and do the same for `<tr>` in the table body; I'm fairly sure for the `th` I can just insert the element separately before the rest but only because there's a single one - I've been having problems figuring out how to do that for both arrays and make sure all the items in the two arrays map correctly to each other

**EDIT 2: Possible solution?** I tried using `XPath Selectors` and I can use them in devTools to select everything I want, but `page.evaluate` doesn't accept them and `page.$x('XPath')` returns `JSHandle@node` since I'm trying to make an array, but I don't know where to go from there

```
let scrapeMemberTable = async (page) => {
 await page.evaluate(() => {
  let ths = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.table-cont > table.tg-2 > thead > tr > th'));
  let trs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.table-cont > table.tg-2 > tbody > tr'));
  // the above two lines of code are the main problem area- I haven't been 
  //able to select all the head/body elements I want in just those two lines of code
 // just removig the table id "tg-2" seems to deselect the whole thing
  const headers = ths.map(th => th.textContent);

  let results = [];

  trs.forEach(tr => {
      let r = {};            
      let tds = Array.from(tr.querySelectorAll('td')).map(td => td.textContent);

      headers.forEach((k,i) => r[k] = tds[i]);
      results.push(r);
  });

  return results; //results is OBJ in JSON format
 }
}

     ...

results = results.concat(            //merge into one array OBJ
        await scrapeMemberTable(page)
    );

     ...
```

Intended Result:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "1",                            <-- this is the goal
        "Sample1": "Swimm",
        "Sample2": "1:30",
        "Sample3": "2:05",
        "Sample4": "1:15",
        "Sample5": "1:41"
    }
]
```

Actual Result:

```
[
    {
        "Sample1": "Swimm",
        "Sample2": "1:30",
        "Sample3": "2:05",
        "Sample4": "1:15",
        "Sample5": "1:41"
    }
]
```

Comment: and what precisely is wrong with how you're scraping it now? You stated an intent but forgot to describe the issue with your existing attempt. Don't make people figure it out, or have to start from scratch, instead make it clear what the deficiency is. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson Hi, thanks for pointing that out- I was half asleep when I finished writing this up so evidently I missed some points; I've added clarification and additional class selectors as a better representation of what's going on, hope that help. Cheers :)

Comment: i don't see any thead or tbody containers in your tables, so the selectors seem problematic.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey -  I completely missed that, thank you; it should be consistent now

Comment: The other thing is you filter on "table.tg-2" but the first table is tg-1, so it won't be included.  Maybe just remove the '.tg-1' from the selector string.